# Multiple select list value interating an extra time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select list item with id "genres". In my code, I get the value of "genres", split it, and then iterate through and adds each value to another array. But for some reason, it's adding an extra entry. Here's my code:

```
if ($("#genres").val()!=null) {
    var genres = $("#genres").val().toString().split(",");
    for (var i in genres) {
        model.TitleGenres.push({ GenreId: genres[i] });
    }
}
```

The variable model.TitleGenres is initialized as [];

When I debug this in Firebug, the values I get are:

```
genres: [ "6", "1770" ]
```

At the end of the loop, I get:

```
model.TitleGenres: [Object { GenreId="6"}, Object { GenreId="1770"}, Object { GenreId=function()}]
```

I have no idea why there is an extra entry with GenreId=function(), can anybody explain why that is and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not iterate over (numerical indexed) arrays in JS with `for in`.

Use `for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) { ... }`

Comment: Why? (I'm not saying you're wrong, but that kind of statement should really be supported with an argument and, ideally, by citing your sources.)

Comment: for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important. ~ MDN

Comment: First answer gets the check. Thanks, kirilloid.

Comment: Because `for...in` iterates Objects, not Arrays. However, basically  array is an object, and that extra value got from `for...in` can be seen in kirilloid's code. It is the `length`-property of the Array-object.

Comment: Actually, you can, but has to check every key with `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

Its cause you iterate over an array with 'for in' and not `foreach` or simpley `for`. With `for in` you iterate over all members of the array object, or in this case jquery object. It seems that one of them is a function. Use `genres.each()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var x = [];
$('#genres option:selected').each( function() { x.push($(this).val()) } );
```

Now "x" will hold all the selected values.